# Emmet short code for table with div

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I tried

```
h1{hello}+table>tr*2>td{$ row}*2^div#list>ul>li{text $}*2
```

but it close `table` tag after `div`

```
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1 row</td>
                <td>2 row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1 row</td>
                <td>2 row</td>
            </tr>
            <div id="list">
                <ul>
                    <li>text 1</li>
                    <li>text 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </table>
```

Please suggest to write proper emmet code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use brackets. Like this:

```
h1{hello}+(table>tr*2>td{$ row}*2)+div#list>ul>li{text $}*2
```

It gives me:

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1 row</td>
        <td>2 row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1 row</td>
        <td>2 row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>text 1</li>
        <li>text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the *climb-up operator* (`^`) but only once, so it “climbed up” only one logical level (i.e. `table>tr>td^div` puts the div on the level of `tr`).

Try climbing higher :D notice the double `^`:

```
h1{hello}+table>tr*2>td{$ row}*2^^div#list>ul>li{text $}*2
```

This gives me

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1 row</td>
        <td>2 row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1 row</td>
        <td>2 row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>text 1</li>
        <li>text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which is exactly what you wanted.